# Rails 5 - single field (text / string) with multiple "versions" dep. on language key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, I have the following case, that I am wondering how to resolve in Rails 5.

In the field `document_keywords` of the model `documenttype` I store keywords used to classify a document. In effect, the language is an attribute to the field `document_keywords` (much like a currency is an attribute to an amount field). Note: the number of to be supported languages is variable.

**Example**

These keywords all belong to the same document type

Document type: Purchase Order

Language: "EN" keywords: "Purchase Order" "Customer Order"

Language: "FR" keywords: "Bon de commande"

Language: "NL" keywords: "bestelling" "bestelbrief"

How should I do this? All help / tips / suggestions much appreciated!

Looks to me like i8n is not the solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: use nested forms where the nested record contains a language attribute